# Power losses in Wire given end load and voltage at load

Tags: power, dc, efficiency, loss

I'm trying to work out the efficiency of power transmission using a small LVDC system. I'm distributing 60VDC from a point and running it over quite a large cable (3-pair cable, 16AWG up to 500m one-way). Initially, I tried to measure the input power to my DC power supply but my current clamp just wasn't accurate enough and gave me really poor readings which give an efficiency of <40% when I work it out (the supply claims to be rated for 90% efficiency itself).

I do have the current through my circuit, and voltage at my load however - 1.94A and 51.5V. From this I can work out a resistance value to represent my load (which was a digital load in this case set to a constant wattage mode of 100W). So with my load, and the resistance of my wire for the forward and return path I have the below circuit:

[image: Circuit]

How I am thinking of solving for the efficiency:

1. Work out resistance of load
2. Add load resistance and wire return path resistance together (the wire resistance is unknown // I want to work it out to match the measurements recorded).
3. Use voltage divider rule for forward path wire and load, since resistance of forward and return path wires are the same
4. Work out wire resistance
5. P = i^2*R multiplied by two for power losses in forward and return path
6. Divide the 100W load by 100W plus the losses obtained above for an efficiency value.
7. 

Originally I thought I could just represent the wire using one resistor at the location Rwire1 in my schematic above, but thought this would not reflect losses in forward and return path. I got a different resistance value using both methods and as a result different efficiencies.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only 2 ways to reduce loses in wires: reduce current or reduce resistance. So or bigger wires o higher voyage and DC-DC converter close to load.

Comment: A voltage drop of 8.5V with a measured current of 1.94A means a total wire resistance of 4.38 ohms and an associated loss of 16.5W.  4.38 ohms is almost exactly the parallel combination of 3x 1km length 16 AWG copper wires.

Comment: _”<40% when I work it out (the supply claims to be rated for 90% efficiency itself)”_ If you measure at super light load, 40 % is possible. If >30 % of rated load, something is strange with your measurement.

Comment: @vir this was the original way I calculated it yes - giving an efficiency of around 85%. Can you walk me through why you treated the wire as one lumped resistor rather than one before and after the load?

Comment: Resistances add in series and if they are all in a series combination - for ideal components - there is no difference in which order they are placed.  In the case of two wiring runs on either side of a load, I cannot think of any substantial deviations from the ideal case that would warrant treating them as separate elements for the purposes of calculating wiring loss.  You could solve the quadratic and find the resistance of the load but you will come up with the same value for power loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the current and the input voltage then you can calculate the power going into the circuit by simply multiplying these two values.

If you know the load voltage and current you can calculate the power dissipated in the load.

Dividing the load power by the input power gives you efficiency.